# Exception at ELSEIF in My SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-python

I had written the stored procedure in My SQL as like below :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Add_Expense
(
    p_Expense_ID            int /* = null */,
    p_Project_ID            int, 
    p_Category_ID       int,
    p_Sub_Category_ID   int,
    p_SupplierID            int,
    p_ExpenseDate       datetime,
    p_Notes             text/* =null */,
    p_Quantity          int,
    p_Price             decimal(18,2),
    p_CreatedBy         int

)
BEGIN
IF((select count(*) from Expense where Category_ID = p_Category_ID AND Sub_Category_ID = p_Sub_Category_ID 
    AND SupplierID = p_SupplierID AND p_Expense_ID IS NULL) > 0)
THEN

    THROW 50005, N'Expense already exists!!!', 1

    ELSEIF ((select count(*) from Expense where Expense_ID = p_Expense_ID) > 0)
    THEN
        Update Expense set Category_ID = p_Category_ID, Sub_Category_ID = p_Sub_Category_ID, SupplierID = p_SupplierID, Quantity = p_Quantity, ExpenseDate = p_ExpenseDate,
        Notes = p_Notes, Price = p_Price, ModifiedBy = p_CreatedBy, ModifiedDate = NOW(), Project_ID= p_Project_ID where Expense_ID = p_Expense_ID;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Expense (Project_ID, Category_ID, Sub_Category_ID, SupplierID, Quantity, Price, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, ExpenseDate, Notes)
        VALUES (p_Project_ID, p_Category_ID, p_Sub_Category_ID, p_SupplierID, p_Quantity, p_Price, p_CreatedBy, NOW(), p_ExpenseDate, p_Notes);
    END IF;
END IF;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

It's throwing the exception at ELSEIF.The exception logic was like if the expense count I get greater than 0 I'm throwing exception as like it already exists. Not getting whats the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not valid MySQL syntax:

```
THROW 50005, N'Expense already exists!!!', 1
```

This looks like SQL Server. In MySQL, you can use `SIGNAL` to raise exceptions from within a block of code, like:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '50005' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Expense already exists!!!';
```

Comment: I had changed to signal. Then It thrown the exception like "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 20" My line No 20 is our signal statement itself.

Comment: @user2413229:  you have an additional, unwanted `END IF` at the end of the procedure.  There should be only one `END IF` instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SIGNAL, not THROW.